# Does GarageBand iOS 1.2 support AirPlay?

Tags: airplay, ios

Does GarageBand iOS 1.2 support AirPlay? I see reports from Google searches that AirPlay was added to an earlier version but had lag-related performance issues. With 1.2, I see no way to select audio output. If I already have a Jambox connected, GarageBand will use it, but so far I can't get it to use AirPlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Treasure Hunt!

On the iPad:

Click the wrench icon to open the Settings dialog. One of the settings is AirPlay - Bluetooth. Set that to On, and the usual audio output selector will appear in the toolbar.

On the iPhone:

Click the gear icon to open an untitled two-sheet settings dialog. Select the Song sheet. The AirPlay - Bluetooth selector is there.

Comment: It's like one of those adventure games where the developers expect the player to keep clicking on stuff until something works.